# Can't update password with jwt spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I had the problem of password encoding with jwt.
This is my signup function, in which I encode the password

```
encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()),
```

I had a problem when I update the user password, I can't sign in after updating my password(I lost the password encryption)

update function :

```
admin.setPassword(encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword())),
```

[image]

this is the result after update :

[image]

please any suggestion.

Comment: Nothing appears in your question, could you please add details?

Comment: in the pictures, there are the line of encryption of the password. do you need the whole function?

Comment: No images appear in your question.

Comment: I just updated, the code, please check it if u can.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?